# How to tag Users to Company?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

As Administrator I created two companies called MLC & BLC.
I Created two users also called Chris & Tom.

I need to tag Chris to MLC company & Tom to BLC.but when i tried in OpenERP 7 Its gives below error.please advice me to sort this issue.

```
ValidateError

Error occurred while validating the field(s) company_id,company_ids: The chosen company is not in the allowed companies for this user
```

@ Priyesh

Still unable to find Allowed Companies

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

You need to add that company first in Allowed Companies, defined in Access Rights tab. Add that company, you want to assign to a user, in that tab and after that, Add it from main Company field. It will work fine.

Comment: It seems that You did not assign Multi Companies group to your current logged user. If you are login with Administrator, Open its form view, Go to Access Rights and at below, Tick the boolean 'Multi Companies' , Save it. Reload it. Re-open the User form view and you will be able to see Allowed Companies tab in Access Rights.